# How to make a decal project on a transparent gameobjects in Unity?

Tags: unity, unity-urp, decal-system

I'm using urp pipeline in Unity 2021.3 and in this version Unity has an official decal system. However, this decal system seems not to support transparent gameobject. I can't project the decal on it.

Also, I've tried [screenspace decal shader](https://github.com/ColinLeung-NiloCat/UnityURPUnlitScreenSpaceDecalShader) from ColinLeung-NiloCat. I still failed to project the decal on a transparent gameobject.

Is there any solution to make a decal project on a transparent gameobject?

Comment: Unfortunately, transparent objects don't write to the G-buffer for us to be able to decal onto their pixels in screen space after the fact. So you'd have to draw the decal as part of the rendering of the transparent object itself. Can you show us what this object is / what kind of material and texture it's using, and what you need to project onto it, so we can tailor a solution to that use case?

Comment: Just a sudden and unexpected idea and then I had a try, both of them failed. So I'm here to ask any alternative. Your solution is a good idea. If I encounter this issue later, I'll use your solution.